# "Activation of network connection failed” for ethernet connection but recovered after system suspension

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend

I understand there have been many similar questions on this site but this issue is different from the rest and I have tried to troubleshoot with answers under other questions. I am seeking a solution for connecting to ethernet upon booting into Ubuntu.

My computer (dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 education) can connect to Wi-Fi upon start-up but the ethernet connection has "Activation of network connection failed” error. When booting into Windows 10 no connection could be made via ethernet, either. Interestingly, upon suspension and re-login in Ubuntu, the ethernet connection is working again. To me this suspension solution cannot be a permanent one.

As compared to the output when the ethernet is working (after suspension), I noticed that the difference between working and non-working output is that IP address for ethernet connection is assigned in working connections (second network entry).

```
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=172.16.221.166 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

The IP of the first network and serial of the last network also changed after restart, but should not make an impact to the connection since they are different in output of two working connections.

The following is the full output of `lshw -C network` at the bottom when ethernet is not working:

```
*-network                 
     description: Wireless interface
     product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 14.3
     bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
     logical name: wlo1
     version: 10
     serial: 04:ea:56:7c:f5:d3
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-27-generic firmware=43.95eb4e97.0 ip=172.17.151.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
     resources: irq:16 memory:7f414000-7f417fff
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0.1
     bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
     logical name: enp3s0f1
     version: 12
     serial: 80:fa:5b:69:63:17
     size: 1Gbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
     resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:7f214000-7f214fff memory:7f210000-7f213fff
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 1
     logical name: docker0
     serial: 02:42:38:43:54:44
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```